# RPI actual SPI communication speed

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I tested my RPI 3B's actual SPI communication speed using the time stamp and spidev of Python. Then, I got the 353.2k bitrate per second when I set the SPI clock as 30MHz. Then, the real SPI communication speed is just 1.18% of RPI hardware rate. Is it the limitation of RPI or any method to increase the SPI speed?. Thanks in advance!.

My code is below. I sent 2 bytes, one for deciding read or write cycle and the last for data for integrating the RPI to FPGA. For example, if I sent [0x00, 0x07], 0x00 is for the write cycle and 0x07 is for data that I want to transfer. If 0x01 is on the first byte then, that is the read cycle.

````
import spidev
import time
import os

speeds = [10000000,20000000,25000000, 30000000, 350000000]

good_tests = []
bad_tests = []
spi=spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.mode = 0b01
spi.bits_per_word = 8

for a in speeds:
    
    print("Testing with SPI Clock = " + str(a))
    spi.max_speed_hz=a 
    good = 0
    bad = 0
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(100000):       
        data_byte = [0,0,0,0]            
        mask = 255
        number = i
        data_byte[0] = int(number>>0 & 255)
        data_byte[1] = int(number>>8 & 255) 
        data_byte[2] = int(number>>16 & 255)
        data_byte[3] = int(number>>24 & 255)

        spi.writebytes2([0x00, data_byte[0]]) #write to address 0
                
        spi.writebytes2([0x01])
        data_in = spi.readbytes(1)
                       
        if data_in[0] == data_byte[0]:
            good = good + 1
        else:
            bad = bad + 1
        
        
        
    stop = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print(stop - start)

    print(good)
    print(bad)
    ```
````

Comment: You have provided no evidence.

Comment: Dear joan, I added some details. Best,

Comment: So you are testing the speed using an interpreter and two byte transactions.  What do you think you are actually timing?

Comment: Well, I would start with the lowest SPI speed, perhaps 100kHz or 50/10kHz (yes, I did use that), I also use Rpi4B Thonny python 3.7.3 built in profile tools and my DS1504 scope to check every byte and bit etc to see what goes wrong. Then I would move up to 100k, 400k, 1MHz etc.